# Mysql - sum values of the same products

Tags: mysql

I'd like some ideas about this:

```
product_id   || tag_id || weight
--------------------------------
4            ||  7     || 5
3            ||  7     || 5
3            ||  7     || 5
3            ||  6     || 3
2            ||  4     || 2
2            ||  6     || 3
1            ||  4     || 2
```

I need something like:
product_x total weight = Y, using Mysql.

The actions should be:

```
if product_id[rowN] == product_id[rowN+1]
then sum(weight[rowN] + weight[rowN+1]
```

I've tried google-ing but couldn't find anything that worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GROUP BY clause automatic group all same product ids and sum these weight.
```

read this for more information  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Try this,

```
SELECT SUM(weight),product_id from tablename group by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id, sum(weight) FROM table GROUP BY product_id
```